# Problem with URL path on WAMP server

Tags: url, include, wamp, relative-path, absolute-path

I'm probably having confusion with relative and absolute paths...

Say I have a file that could be ***anywhere*** on my directory. I want to use PHP include to include a footer.php file. This footer file is always located at my root/template directory.

So I type the following `<?php include('./template/footer.php'); ?>`

But alas, WAMP cannot find it! What am I doing wrong here?

I've tried `<?php include('../template/footer.php'); ?>` also, but it doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

If you meant 'root' to be relative to your current Apache site's web root, then you would want to use:

```
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/template/folder.php'); ?>
```

note (for anyone else reading) that DOCUMENT_ROOT is not populated on (at least older versions of) IIS. But you should be fine since you're using Apache.

---

If you instead were referring to 'root' as the filesystem root, then root/template would be:

```
<?php include('/template/folder.php'); ?>
```

- the **`./`** path fragment prefix references your current directory
  (relative to whatever file is now being processed) (relative path).
- the **`../`** path fragment prefix references the parent directory
  (relative to whatever file is now being processed) (relative path).
- the **`/`** path fragment prefix references the root filesystem
  directory (absolute path).

Always remember that includes are based on the filesystem of the server itself, not on the served site's URI pathing, even if they may mirror each other when only looking at relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to try only `<?php include('template/footer.php'); ?> the`../` is use to access out side the folder